# Receiving "no apps can perform this action" while starting activty

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

So I am trying to run an activity and I am getting the "No app can perform this action" while clicking the button from a fragment.

The First Main activity intent declaration:

```
 Intent setTable = new Intent(this, setTable.class);
```

the method run by button click:

```
@Override
public void miscNext(){

    startActivity(setTable);

}
```

Fragment button on click:

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                for(int i = 0; i < data.getDays(); i++){
                    String tempChecker = miscNum[i].getText().toString();

                    if(!tempChecker.isEmpty()){

                        data.setBreaks(i, Integer.parseInt(miscNum[i].getText().toString()));

                    } else{

                        break;
                    }

                    if(i == (data.getDays() - 1)){
                        data.setDoneNames(true);

                    }

                }

                data.initNamesArray();

                if(data.isDoneNames()){

                    activityCommander.miscNext();
                }
            }
        });
```

The other activity, default tabbed activity only onCreate changed:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_table);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        final TextView day           = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        final Spinner  spinnerList[] = new Spinner[data.getSessions(mViewPager.getCurrentItem())];
        final TextView session[]     = new TextView[data.getSessions(mViewPager.getCurrentItem())];

        day.setText(getDay(data.getFirstDay() + mViewPager.getCurrentItem()));

        mViewPager.addView(day);

        //Rules

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams spinner = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams dayRule = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);



        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data.getNamesArray());
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        for(int i = 0; i < data.getDays(); i++){

            spinnerList[i] = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
            session[i] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

            spinnerList[i].setAdapter(adapter);

            mViewPager.addView(session[i], dayRule);
            mViewPager.addView(spinnerList[i], spinner);

        }


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

And the logcat

```
11-23 14:21:07.865 9531-9531/com.example.user.timetable_test I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id: time:27674782
11-23 14:21:15.630 9531-9531/com.example.user.timetable_test V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{7612187 token=android.os.BinderProxy@942882f {com.example.user.timetable_test/com.example.user.timetable_test.setup.Set_Up}} show : false
11-23 14:21:19.375 9531-9761/com.example.user.timetable_test D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
11-23 14:21:19.385 9531-9531/com.example.user.timetable_test W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
11-23 14:21:19.385 9531-9531/com.example.user.timetable_test W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
11-23 14:21:19.385 9531-9531/com.example.user.timetable_test W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
11-23 14:21:19.385 9531-9531/com.example.user.timetable_test W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
11-23 14:21:19.385 9531-9531/com.example.user.timetable_test W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
11-23 14:21:19.400 9531-9531/com.example.user.timetable_test I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@942882f time:27686319
```

This may be a bit off topic, but does anyone know how to add widgets pro grammatically to the tabs?

Comment: can you post your logcat

Comment: Where do you set `activityCommander ` ?

Comment: In the fragment, I did this to all the other fragments, about 4 or 5, and the button worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you change

```
@Override
public void miscNext(){

    startActivity(setTable);
}
```

by

```
@Override
public void miscNext(){

    startActivity(new Intent(this, setTable.class));

}
```

Btw, If I understood well, the Overriden method `public void miscNext()` is within an Activity, right?

Anyway, one recommendations apart from the problem is in Java it is recommended to name the class with the first letter as capital letter, so it means this way:

> public class SetTable

instead of

> public class setTable

Comment: maybe the logcat would help?

Comment: BTW, nothing happens

Comment: Did you declare correctly the "setTable" Activity on your Manifest? What's the Activity which you want to launch the "setTable" Activity? Is it visible when trying to launch it???

Comment: I have declared properly in the manifest, it is a tabbed scrolling activity, the default one, and what do you mean by 'is it visible'?

Comment: By it is visible, I mean that the "this" from the Activity which is launching that is currently visible. Otherwise.........can you try to add to the Intent the intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); ?? Intent intent = new Intent(context, setTable.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

Comment: Does it give me any errors, adding `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`? No, Does it change anything?Also no. BTW, can I add a tabbed activity as a fragment?

Comment: Tried it again after remaking the tabbed activity and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fragments, instead of:

```
Intent setTable = new Intent(this, setTable.class);
```

use:

```
Intent setTable = new Intent(getActivity, setTable.class);
```

Comment: maybe the logcat would help?